# circular user interface with java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I'm trying to develop a circular interface which contains a clock or any other information 
My problem is that with swing I didn't found a solution to make a stanadard frame look round ..
any help please ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4287453/4028085

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18935945/4028085

Comment: thanks for your quick answer ! 
I will look at it .

Comment: You're welcome! Here is another link you might be interested in...http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/24476755/4028085